# Estimating the Probability in a statistical analysis

Tags: mean, random-variable, standard-deviation, kernel-trick, histogram

I am carrying out a statistical analysis where I run the simulation (Matlab) 5000 times, to get 5000 results. The objective is to estimate the probability of having a result that is less than or equal to a specific value. The resulted data does not follow any known statistical distribution. Therefore, in order to estimate the probability. I have two options:

Option 1: Fit the data and estimate probability using kernel distribution (Matlab ksdensity).

Option 2: Use Matlab histcount function with a very high number of bins to estimate the probability.

Which method is more correct? and which is better?

thanks

Comment: You could also directly use the empirical CDF.

Comment: The recommendation by @Arya is the most accurate (in the absence of any other information) and amounts to a more efficient calculation of Option 2 in the limit of arbitrarily many bins.  However, in many circumstances you *do* have additional information, such as a small family of distributions likely to include yours; and in such cases, you can often do much better than any of these approaches.  If that's your situation, tell us more about your analysis and what you know.